# How to define multiple parameters with names containing numeric identifiers

Tags: matlab

I have some files with names `f0.csv, f1.csv, f2.csv, ..., f100.csv`. I want to read these files one by one and then put the content of them in parameters with names such as data0, data1, data2, ...., something like this:

```
data0 = load('f0.csv'); 
data1 = load('f1.csv'); 
...
```

how can I write these better and more well-structured. thanks a lot.

Comment: Take a look at [readtable](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readtable.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looping through the files is no issue, however naming variables with numbers (data0, data1, data2) is terrible practice and really diffficult to handle at some point, so I strongly recommend something like a cellarray where you can access the data by `data(1)` and so on.

```
lastfile=2;
data=cell(lastfile,1);

for i=1:lastfile
    data(i)={load(['f' int2str(i) '.csv'])};
end
```

However you asked for it and it is possible. With [`eval`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eval.html) you can create those variables.

```
for i=1:lastfile
    eval(['data' int2str(i) '=load(''f' int2str(i) '.csv'')']);
end
```